# Which MIME type is correct for the .exe file?

Tags: http-headers, mime-types, mime, file-extension

I try to find which MIME type corresponds to the each extension and I get ambiguous results.

According to [webdesign.about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-file-extension.htm) the correct MIME for `exe` is: `application/octet-stream`

According to [freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) the correct MIME for `exe` is: `application/x-msdownload` and it says that `application/octet-stream` is MIME for `bin` extension.

According to [iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) the correct MIME for `exe` (or something called vnd.microsoft.portable-executable as I don't see exe there) is: `application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable`

Which website is the most accurate because I don't know what kind of content type value I should expect on the server site in the HTTP header.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable) is a registered MIME type and its description matches what you want to use it for.

The `x-` prefix in application/x-msdownload indicates that it is **experimental** so it should generally be avoided: Especially if something standard is available as it in in this case.

[application/octet-stream](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream) is for arbitrary collection of bytes. It does match an executable file, but it isn't as specific as application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable.

Use **`application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable`**

Comment: What about using 'application/exe' this seems made for the job - https://www.file-extensions.org/exe-file-extension

Comment: @TinoMclaren - There is no standard for `application/exe`. That seems like a website which has noted some non-standard things people have used.

Comment: @Quintin Ah I see, so iana.org is the truth. Bookmarked, thanks.