# Is it necessary to add "AddType" line for .exe and .htm?

Tags: html, .htaccess, mime-types

Recently I review my .htaccess file and notice there are no AddType line for .exe and .htm file types, like below:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/octet-stream .exe 
    AddType text/html .htm
</IfModule>
```

However, the strange thing is that the browser still can download .exe file instead of showing it in browser. And showing .htm instead of download it. Why? And is it necessary to add "AddType" fro these two types?

Comment: This is a strange question ... If you see that things work as expected, then why do you ask whether it might be necessary to add those directives?

Comment: @arkascha, Thank you for your comment. My question is why it works as expected even I do not add "AddType" clauses?

Comment: Multiple reasons: 1. most likely those mime types are already listed in the actual http server's configuration, so you don't have to additionally add them in _distributed_ configuration files over and over again. 2. such mime types only result in extra headers being prepended to the delivered payload. Those headers are not required if the client (the browser) does not need help to identify the mime type by itself. 3. Most http server's are pretty good at dynamically determining a file's mime type in a dynamic manner and 4. the fallback behavior to handle unknown mime types is to download it.

Comment: In general one can say the "file name extensions" are a thing of the past. They were useful in the 1980th, but modern systems do not really care for them. It is much easier and more precise to dynamically determine a file's mime type by peeking into it's content. There is one notable exception from this, as always: some parts of MS windows still rely on "file name extensions", notable the file manager. One more reason to use other operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These mime-types are most certainly already defined in the server config. Although not necessarily explicitly with the `AddType` directive.

However, the mime-type for `.exe` files is more likely to be defined as `application/x-msdownload` (or possibly `application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable`), rather than `application/octet-stream`. See this related StackOverflow question: [Which MIME type is correct for the .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459168/which-mime-type-is-correct-for-the-exe-file)

These mime-types are listed in the `mime.types` config file (the location of which is defined by mod_mime's [`TypesConfig` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#typesconfig)) that is read in by Apache/mod_mime at startup. `mime.types` contains a list of mappings of mime-type to file extension. For example:

> ```
> application/x-msdownload       exe dll com bat msi
> text/html                      html htm
> ```

For the complete list:
https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

And for the official list of registered mime-types with iana.org, see:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

---

> the browser still can download .exe file instead of showing it in browser.

Browser's don't normally known how to handle "`.exe` files". If the browser receives a response with a mime-type (`Content-Type` header) that it does not understand it will most likely prompt to download/save it.

Comment: `/etc/mime.types` on my Ubuntu server has `application/x-msdos-program    com exe bat dll`, so the mime type that is served will probably depend on your system in addition to your web server.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Curious, I wonder why Ubuntu uses `application/x-msdos-program`? The "correct/official" mime-type is `application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable`, although `application/x-msdownload` (which would seem to be a historical / de facto standard) is still distributed by Apache AFAICT.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also find /etc/mime.types in my Linux(CentOS 6.8) which contains both exe and htm.